# Server forcibly closing connection when attempting SSL connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I'm trying to create an ssl connection between server and client, but I keep getting a `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` error.

**client.py**

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.init_sock).start()
    def init_sock(self):
        host = 'localhost'
        port = 49374
        baresock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM)
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
        self.servsock = context.wrap_socket(baresock, server_hostname=host)
        try:
            self.servsock.connect((host, port))  #<--- Line error is being thrown at
            logging.info("Connection Successful")
        except:
            logging.info("Connection Problem")
            return
        threading.Thread(target=self.listen_loop).start()
```

And **server.py**:

```
class ClientHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        pass

class Server(socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer):
    srvhost = ''
    srvport = 49374

    def __init__(self,
                 request_handler_class=ClientHandler,
                 certfile="../scache/cert.pem",
                 keyfile="../scache/key.pem",
                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
                 bind_and_activate=True):
        self.address_family = socket.AF_INET6
        self.certfile = certfile
        self.keyfile = keyfile
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version
        server_address = (self.srvhost, self.srvport)
        super(Server, self).__init__(server_address, request_handler_class, bind_and_activate)

    def get_request(self):
        newsocket, fromaddr = self.socket.accept()
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.certfile, keyfile=self.keyfile) # <------ Hanging Here
        logging.info("New Request from " + fromaddr[0])
        connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
        logging.info("Socket Wrapped")
        return connstream, fromaddr
```

When I attempt to connect to the Server from the Client, The client throws the WinError 10054 as noted above.  When I try to use the debugger on the Server side, I can follow the error to `socketserver.py`'s `_handle_request_noblock` method where `request, client_address = self.get_request()` is throwing an OSError.  Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Project/src/client.py", line 36, in init_sock
    self.servsock.connect((host, port))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1093, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1084, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

What is causing this error, and how do I troubleshoot it?  Thanks.

Comment: can you include the full OSError?

Comment: Added full traceback.

Comment: that's the client side... which just looks like the ssl handshake failed. what was the OSError on the server side? looks like it's not able to load the certs for some reason. btw, do you have certifi installed (through pip or whatever)?

Comment: @corley-brigman I can't see the details on the OSError, just when I step through the server execution in debug, in `socketserver.py`, there's a part that goes:

         try:
            request, client_address = self.get_request()
        except OSError:
            return
And that's where its hitting

Comment: so, the next useful step is to see what the error actually is (it will have more information). you can add either a 'import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` after the except line, or add an `import pdb/ipdb; pdb/ipdb.set_trace()` after the except line (and in that case, change `except OSError` to `except OSError as e`, so you can introspect the exception object).

Comment: @CorleyBrigman the problem is that the OSError is being thrown in `socketserver.py`, not in one of my files.  Is it going to be a problem to edit it?

Comment: Normally, no - it's just another regular file on your hard drive (just remember to save a copy so you can restore it back to its proper condition). On some systems, if it's in a system framework, you may need to `sudo` it, but since that looks like a user-installed anaconda, it should just be a regular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to duplicate this, I used your code and had the same issue and then realized that I was missing the `certfile` and `keyfile` that are referenced in the constructor.  I generated the files and put them in a relative path using the following code:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto

CRT_PATH = "../scache/cert.pem"  # self-signed certificate
KEY_PATH = "../scache/key.pem"  # private key used to sign the certificate


def generate_key():
    """
    Generate a private key and dump it to the key file.
    :return: key
    """
    key = crypto.PKey()
    key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 4096)
    with open(KEY_PATH, "w") as keyfile:
        keyfile.write(bytes.decode(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)))
    return key


def generate_crt(key):
    """
    Generate a self-signed certificate.
    :return: certificate
    """
    crt = crypto.X509()
    crt.get_subject().C = "US"
    crt.get_subject().ST = "New York"
    crt.get_subject().L = "New York"
    crt.get_subject().O = "CompanyName"
    crt.get_subject().OU = "UnitName"
    crt.get_subject().CN = "localhost"
    crt.set_pubkey(key)
    crt.set_serial_number(101010)
    crt.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    crt.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    crt.sign(key, 'sha256')  # Self-sign
    with open(CRT_PATH, "w") as crtfile:
        crtfile.write(bytes.decode(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, crt)))
    return crt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_crt(generate_key())
```

Once I generated the certfile and keyfile that you noted, the `OSError` was no longer throwing and the app could continue with the handshake.  This leads me to believe that the likely culprit of the problem is an invalid path to the certfile/keyfile, or the file is invalid.

You can adjust the paths to be whatever you need them to be (I assumed this script would be in the same location as your client.py and server.py) and you should probably adjust the parameters of the certificate to whatever you need for your particular app.